# Device Not Found, libUsb .Net

Tags: c#, libusb

```
 public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x20DF, 0x0001);

 // Find and open the usb device.
 MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

 // If the device is open and ready
 if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");
```

See the screen shot below for where I pulled the VendorID and ProductID

[alt text http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7197/screen1uv.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7197/screen1uv.png)

So why does the USBFinder Keep returning null?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I guess answering it might help someone else. I experienced the same until I found out I needed to setup the filter driver for each device I want to be able to communicate with. I did this using the Filter Wizard, which can be found in the installation path for `LibUsbDotNet`.

In my case I could reach it from Start-> All Programs -> LibUsbDotNet -> libusb_win32 -> Filter Wizard, which actually executes C:\Program Files\LibUsbDotNet\libusb-win32\install-filter-win.exe
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found libusb does this too, not sure why, but you can retry the search a few times.

Comment: Even if I run it 5 times in a row, it still fails